# ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "oth"

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have a problem with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(oth.book) FROM book_meta_keywords oth, 
                (SELECT bmk.meta_keyword AS metaKeyword, bmk.book AS book FROM books b
                    INNER JOIN customers_books cvb ON cvb.book = b.id
                    INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk ON bmk.book = b.id
                    WHERE cvb.customer = 1 ) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
            INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
            WHERE oth.meta_keyword = allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.metaKeyword AND oth.book != allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.book AND b.status = 'GOOD'
```

I am getting below error for this query.

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "oth"
LINE 6:             INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "oth", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
, Time: 0.002000s

But if I run the below query it works

```
SELECT DISTINCT(oth.book) FROM book_meta_keywords oth, 
                (SELECT bmk.meta_keyword AS metaKeyword, bmk.book AS book FROM books b
                    INNER JOIN customers_books cvb ON cvb.book = b.id
                    INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk ON bmk.book = b.id
                    WHERE cvb.customer = 1 ) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
            WHERE oth.meta_keyword = allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.metaKeyword AND oth.book != allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.book
```

Can anyone help me why... query is basically trying to get similar books based on purchased books based on their meta keywords.

thanks.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT and works on the whole selected rows. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT oth.book ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: thanks, but I think others have understood the question and gave me working answers which I appreciate.

Comment: I understood the question, I said it was a faq, that is not the point, this isn't a help desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `FROM`  clause:

```
FROM 
    book_meta_keywords oth, 
    (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
    INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
```

You are mixing explicit and implicit joins (the latter is denoted by the comma). Don't. They have different prescendence rules and the query planner ends up evaluating the the second condiiton before `oth` was seen.

As for how to solve this: *assuming* that the logic is indeed what you want, that's a lateral join:

```
FROM 
    book_meta_keywords oth 
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
    INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
```

I suspect, however, that your query could be further simplified. You might want to ask another question for this, explaning the purpose of the query and providing a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053471/find-similar-books-based-on-purchased-books-based-on-book-meta-keywords

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `join`

```
SELECT DISTINCT oth.book FROM book_meta_keywords oth join
                (SELECT bmk.meta_keyword AS metaKeyword, bmk.book AS book FROM books b
                    INNER JOIN customers_books cvb ON cvb.book = b.id
                    INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk ON bmk.book = b.id
                    WHERE cvb.customer = 1 ) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
on oth.meta_keyword = allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.metaKeyword and 
   oth.book != allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.book
            INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
            WHERE  b.status = 'GOOD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it can work :

```
SELECT DISTINCT oth.book 
FROM book_meta_keywords oth
     INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
     , (SELECT bmk.meta_keyword AS metaKeyword, bmk.book AS book 
        FROM books b
        INNER JOIN customers_books cvb ON cvb.book = b.id
        INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk ON bmk.book = b.id
        WHERE cvb.customer = 1 ) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
WHERE oth.meta_keyword = allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.metaKeyword 
     AND oth.book != allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.book 
     AND b.status = 'GOOD'
```

But does this do what you need...