# find similar books based on purchased books based on book meta keywords

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

As the title suggest i want to find similar books based on customer purchased books based on the meta keywords. Below query works but Ive been told this can be simplified.

```
SELECT DISTINCT oth.book 
FROM book_meta_keywords oth
     INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = oth.book
     , (SELECT bmk.meta_keyword AS metaKeyword, bmk.book AS book 
        FROM books b
        INNER JOIN customers_books cvb ON cvb.book = b.id
        INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk ON bmk.book = b.id
        WHERE cvb.customer = 1 ) AS allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta 
WHERE oth.meta_keyword = allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.metaKeyword 
     AND oth.book != allCustomerPurchasedBooksMeta.book 
     AND b.status = 'GOOD'
```

Table structures

```
book_meta_keywords
book       meta_keyword
1            history
1            culture
2            culture
3            facts

books
id    status
1      GOOD
1      GOOD 
2       GOOD
3       GOOD

customers_books
book       customer
1            90
```

I should get the output book - 2.

Hope my table data works for you if not let me know happy to correct it.

UPDATE

I am using the below query now

```
SELECT bmk2.book
            FROM customers_books cb
            INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk1 
                ON  bmk1.book = cb.book
            INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk2 
                ON bmk2.meta_keyword = bmk1.meta_keyword
                AND bmk2.book <> bmk1.book
            INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = bmk2.book
            
            WHERE cb.customer = 1 AND b.status = 'PUBLISHED'

            GROUP BY bmk2.book
            ORDER BY MAX(b.modified_date) DESC
```

And this query returns

```
13
3
11
```

But I am expecting only 3 because customer has already purchased books 13 and 11.
To see customer purchased books you can run the below below query which returns 13, 11

```
SELECT c.book FROM customers_books c WHERE c.customer = 1
```

Full table structure and SQL is provided in the DB fiddle below.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tovUePp2WVffXLcuaxmJ8K/5

what do you think is the issue. I think
this line `AND bmk2.book <> bmk1.book` isnt working.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: What is your question? Your EDIT is unclear. But--Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. Please put what is needed in your post, not just at a link. That includes the code part of a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output. PS Comma has lower precedence than keyword joins, so mixing them can confuse. PS Working code questions belong on [codereview.se]. PS What have you learned researching an answer to simplifying? [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: @philipxy is this okay now ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with joins:

```
select bmk2.book
from customer_books cb
inner join book_meta_keyword bmk1 
    on  bmk1.book = cb.book
inner join book_meta_keyword bmk2 
    on  bmk2.meta_keyword = bmk1.meta_keyword
    and bmk2.book <> bmk1.book
where cb.customer = 1
```

The query starts from books that customer 1 purchased, then bring the corresponding keywords, and finally get all other books that have any keyword in common.

Notes:

- If there are several matching keywords across books, then you will get duplicate in the resultset. In that case use `select distinct`
- You don't need table `book` to get the result you want - if needed for some reason, you can bring it with one more join

Comment: what if i want to bring books which has GOOD status ?

Comment: @Eric: that's another join at the end of the`from` clause, to bring table `book`  (using column `bmk2.book`), then filtering on the `status` in `where` cause...

Comment: your a legend. it works perfectly now. very simplified code.

Comment: if i want to add order by book.created_date DESC how can i add that in ? i am getting ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 19: WHERE cb.customer = 1 ORDER BY b.created_date DESC

Comment: @Eric: so add that column to the `select` clause as well...

Comment: having issues with the query now. I have updated the answer