# Cant figure out whats wrong with my query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to find similar books based on purchased books based on book meta keywords but the query below returns books which user already have purchased too. I need to bring books which arent purchased but are similar based on his purchases. Hope thats clear.

Below is the link for query and data and results.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tovUePp2WVffXLcuaxmJ8K/3

Query shouldnt return data which returned by this below query. But its returning some of below data too.

```
SELECT c.book FROM customers_books c WHERE c.customer = 1
```

Comment: How is this question different from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053471/find-similar-books-based-on-purchased-books-based-on-book-meta-keywords where you accepted the answer?

Comment: i know, i found out its not working after more data.

Comment: Then you should have edited the original question. This is just a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try with below query?
I have added left join into the existing query to remove already purchased books.

```
SELECT bmk2.book
FROM book_meta_keywords bmk2
INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk1 
                ON  bmk2.meta_keyword = bmk1.meta_keyword
INNER JOIN customers_books cb 
                ON bmk1.book = cb.book
INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = bmk2.book
LEFT JOIN customers_books cbp ON cbp.book = b.id 
                    and cbp.customer = 1
WHERE cb.customer = 1 AND b.status = 'PUBLISHED'
and cbp.book IS NULL
GROUP BY bmk2.book
ORDER BY MAX(b.modified_date) DESC ;
```

Answer (score -1):

If the two queries are in the same form, you can simply EXCEPT them.

See this for more info:
https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/except.php

Comment: Postgres does not support MINUS - only the standard EXCEPT operator